# Compare Value between two datagridview cells

Tags: c#

I am having two datagridview named `dgv1` and `dgv2`, each row in datagridview one is unique with some ID. Consider I am having `ID`, `Quantity`, `Price` & `Total` fields.

First, I am copying all the values of `dgv1` to `dgv2`. After that I am changing Quantity value in `dgv2`, if the quantity in `dgv2` is greater than the quantity in `dgv1` for specific id then it should not change the value or should show a message or something like that.

Hope I have clearly explained, below are the working codes. It is working fine for copying, editing, multiplying but I need help for comparing the datagridview quantity values.

```
   private void btnCopyTo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (DataGridViewRow item in dataGridView1.Rows)
        {
            if ((bool)item.Cells[0].Value == true)
            {
                int n = dataGridView3.Rows.Add();

                dataGridView3.Rows[n].Cells[0].Value = item.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
                dataGridView3.Rows[n].Cells[1].Value = item.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
                dataGridView3.Rows[n].Cells[2].Value = item.Cells[2].Value.ToString();
                dataGridView3.Rows[n].Cells[3].Value = item.Cells[3].Value.ToString();

            }
        }       
    }

    private void dataGridView3_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView3.Rows)
        {
            row.Cells[dataGridView3.Columns[3].Index].Value = (Convert.ToDouble(row.Cells[dataGridView3.Columns[2].Index].Value) * Convert.ToDouble(row.Cells[dataGridView3.Columns[1].Index].Value));
        }
    }
```

Comment: where is your comparison attempt code? how is it not working?

Answer (score 0):

Your mean?? I don't understant clearly.

```
  private void CompareData()
    {
        for (int i = dataGridView1.RowCount - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < dataGridView3.RowCount - 1; j++)
            {
                if(Convert.ToDouble(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString()) >= Convert.ToDouble(dataGridView3.Rows[j].Cells[1].Value.ToString()))
                {
                   //handle

                }
            }
        }

    }
```